# Is it OK to use ES6 classes for Vuex modules, mutations and actions?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, es6-class

I am going to create reusable Vuex modules this way:

```
// parent class to keep all the common CRUD actions
class ListModule {
    state: getInitialState(),
    actions: new ListActions(),
    mutations: new ListMutations()
}

...
class FooMutations extends ListMutations {
    // some additional mutations
}

// class with parent's actions and data structure, but modified mutations
class FooModule extends ListModule {
    mutations: new FooMutations()
}
```

This is how I would like to avoid duplicating CRUD operations and extend them for certain modules if it is necessary.

All modules will be used with namespacing.

Are there any potential problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible but it seems unnecessarily complicated to use classes when you just need objects.

```js
const listMutations = {
  // mutations here
}

// 'extend' listMutations
const fooMutations = {
  ...listMutations,
  // some additional mutations
}

const listModule = {
  state: getInitialState(),
  actions: listActions,
  mutations: listMutations
}

// 'extend' listModule
const fooModule = {
  ...listModule,
  mutations: fooMutations
}
```